# Firefox Jquery Draggable Issue With Resizing Outer Div

Tags: jquery, firefox, html, user-interface, resize

I've set up an example here: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/TheGodEmperor/hZJ9S/)

Basically, only in firefox does it rescale the outer div's size while you're dragging. I think it has to deal with the relative positioning. I was wondering how to fix this issue with the jquery UI. I've been reading up on the API and searching for other questions that had anything in relation, but I've had no luck so far.

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: can't be able to drag in provided link

Comment: huh, that's odd. I'll see if I can fix it to add the jquery ui library then.

Comment: Does the same in IE9 as well. Only works in Chrome.

Comment: That's interesting, cause in IE8 it doesn't do that (I've not yet bothered to upgrade to 9 for some reason). When I checked Opera, Chrome, and Safari they were fine too. Was only FF that had the weird resizing thing.

Comment: FYI @j08691's solution seems to work in both as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about setting the helper option to clone?

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hZJ9S/6/)**

Comment: Ah, that is an interesting idea. I'd just have to make sure there's a visual way to make sure people realize they aren't duplicating it, just a placeholder for showing where it was.

I'll just add a style to it while it's being dragged.

Still find it weird that Firefox handles it differently from other browsers in regards to relative and the parent div.

Comment: Ah doh, didn't think about something so simple :P hah. Nice.

Thank you for the help :)

Comment: @TheGodEmperor - if you feel this answer helped solve your problem, consider selecting it as the accepted answer.